# Should I try to access self in a PointerPressed event handler for a CoreApp in the Rust Crate for Windows?

Tags: windows, rust

E0759 self has an anonymous lifetime '_ but it need to satisfy a 'static lifetime requirement. E0759 self has an anonymous lifetime '_ but it need to satisfy a 'static lifetime requirement. E0759 self has an anonymous lifetime '_ but it need to satisfy a 'static lifetime requirement. E0759 self has an anonymous lifetime '_ but it need to satisfy a 'static lifetime requirement.

```
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]

use windows::{
    core::*,
    Foundation::*,
    ApplicationModel::Core::*,
    Foundation::Numerics::*,
    Foundation::TypedEventHandler,
    Win32::System::Com::*,
    UI::{
        Core::*,
        Composition::*,
    },
    
};

use windows as Windows;

#[implement(Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkViewSource)]
struct App();

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
impl App {
    fn CreateView(&self) -> Result<IFrameworkView> {
        // TODO: need self query `self.into()` to support implementing both IFrameworkViewSource and IFrameworkView on the same object.
        Ok(AppView::new().into())
    }
}

#[implement(Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkView)]
struct AppView {
    m_target: Option<CompositionTarget>,
    m_visuals: Option<VisualCollection>,
    m_selected: Option<Visual>,
    m_offset: Option<Vector2>,
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
impl AppView {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            m_target: None,
            m_visuals: None,
            m_selected: None,
            m_offset: None,
        }
    }

    fn Initialize(&self, _: &Option<CoreApplicationView>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn Load(&self, _: &HSTRING) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn Uninitialize(&self) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn Run(&self) -> Result<()> {
        let window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()?;
        window.Activate()?;

        let dispatcher = window.Dispatcher()?;
        dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessUntilQuit)?;

        Ok(())
    }

    fn SetWindow(&mut self, window: &Option<CoreWindow>) -> Result<()> {
        let compositor = Compositor::new()?;
        let root = compositor.CreateContainerVisual()?;
        self.m_target = Some(compositor.CreateTargetForCurrentView()?);
        let target = self.m_target.as_ref().unwrap();
        target.SetRoot(&root)?;
        self.m_visuals = Some(root.Children()?);
        let visuals = self.m_visuals.as_ref().unwrap(); // extra line for test is ok
        window.as_ref().unwrap().PointerPressed(TypedEventHandler::<CoreWindow, PointerEventArgs>::new(move |_, args|
            {
                let args = args.as_ref().unwrap();
                let currentpoint = args.CurrentPoint().unwrap();
                let point = currentpoint.Position().unwrap(); // Point not Vector2

                //let visuals: &VisualCollection = self.m_visuals.as_ref().unwrap();
                let visuals = self.m_visuals.as_ref().unwrap(); // E0759 self has an anonymous lifetime '_ but it need to satisfy a 'static lifetime requirement

                Ok(())
            }
        ))?;
        window.as_ref().unwrap().PointerMoved(TypedEventHandler::<CoreWindow, PointerEventArgs>::new(move |_, _args|
            {
                Ok(())
            }
        ))?;
        window.as_ref().unwrap().PointerReleased(TypedEventHandler::<CoreWindow, PointerEventArgs>::new(move |_, _args|
            {
                Ok(())
            }
        ))?;

        Ok(())
    }

    fn AddVisual(_point: Point) {
        //...
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        CoInitializeEx(std::ptr::null_mut(), COINIT_MULTITHREADED)?;
    }

    let app: IFrameworkViewSource = App().into();
    CoreApplication::Run(app)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: have you tried passing a closure [like so](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-samples-rs/blob/2e6c5578a2d6199eeabd9d49389290c4ced68f3c/webview2/src/main.rs#L274) and then using self from there? would it work? if not, could you post a compiler error?

Comment: A closure compiles for one event handler but only if I don't use 'move'. When I add another closure to handle OnPointerReleased and attempt to access a member I get compiler error E0524 - two closures require unique access to 'self.selected' at the same time.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet where you do subscribe to 2 events, and update the question with the error details?

Comment: The problem might be that you need to share self.selected or self using some interior mutability pattern, but it's hard to say for sure without seeing your code.

Comment: I should have posted more code earlier. Thinking an Arc wrapping of the struct member might fix this.

window.as_ref().unwrap().PointerMoved(TypedEventHandler::<CoreWindow, PointerEventArgs>::new(/*move */|_, _args|
            {
                Ok(())
            }
        ))?;
        window.as_ref().unwrap().PointerReleased(TypedEventHandler::<CoreWindow, PointerEventArgs>::new(/*move */|_, _args|
            {
                //E0524
                //self.m_selected = None; // &'static mut self above
                Ok(())
            }
        ))?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

Comment: Try using a Cell<Option<bool>> for m_selected.

Comment: m_selected is actually an Option<windows::UI::Composition::Visual> rather than a bool. I will try to wrap the Visual in a Cell<Option<>>.

Comment: I now get an E0501 on the second event handler: 'cannot borrow self.m_selected as immutable as the previous handler requires unique access' I borrowed self as 'static to get the first event handler to build which could be a problem. This was because 'move' would not build with the first handler only. The function containing the two closures is: fn SetWindow(&'static mut self, window: &Option<CoreWindow>) -> Result<()> {//...}

Comment: I'd avoid `'static`. Could you post your full code and the error in the question details above?

Comment: Full code and revised question posted above.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also post all compiler error messages if you remove `'static` and add `move`-s ? What code do you want to put into PointerReleased? Could you add it as well?

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: Thanks. The error message is confusing. Could you screenshot it maybe? Also where is line 97 in this? The line number doesn't seem to match your code.

Comment: I simplified the code and the error message above incuding a comment on the line that triggers the message.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing AppView's instance self reference in v0.30 doesn't seem to be possible, because `TypedEventHandler::new` has a `+ 'static` requirement for the callback ([see](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Foundation/struct.TypedEventHandler.html#method.new)), so any reference it captures must be `'static` (a global variable basically).

Please raise an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues) if you want this. Your code looks like a reasonable way to use this API.

Until then, as a workaround you could make a level of indirection, where instead of storing the state directly in AppView, you store it in a shared helper object, for example:

```
struct AppView {
    m_state: Rc<RefCell<AppViewState>>,
}

struct AppViewState {
    m_target: Option<CompositionTarget>,
    m_visuals: Option<VisualCollection>,
    m_selected: Option<Visual>,
    m_offset: Option<Vector2>,
}
```

You can clone it move into the callback for modification:

```
let pointer_pressed_state = Rc::clone(self.m_state);
let pointer_pressed_handler = TypedEventHandler::<CoreWindow, PointerEventArgs>::new(move |_, args| {
    let state_ref = pointer_pressed_state.borrow(); // or .borrow_mut()
    ...
});

let pointer_moved_state = Rc::clone(self.m_state);
let pointer_moved_handler = TypedEventHandler::<CoreWindow, PointerEventArgs>::new(move |_, args| {
    let state_ref = pointer_moved_state.borrow(); // or .borrow_mut()
    ...
});
```

This should work, because now the closure doesn't capture any references (everything gets moved).

If you want, you can add methods to AppViewState, and call them from the closures like `state_ref.OnPointerPressed(...)`.

Another option that I don't recommend is to use unsafe and cast self to 'static.

Answer (score 0):

Rc<RefCell> gives a thread related compiler error but changing to Arc<Mutex> resolves this.

```
struct AppView {
    m_state: Arc<Mutex<AppViewState>>,
}

struct AppViewState {
    m_target: Option<CompositionTarget>,
    m_visuals: Option<VisualCollection>,
    m_selected: Option<Visual>,
    m_offset: Option<Vector2>,
}
```